# fetch synonym of a word

Tags: php, dictionary, synonym

Is there any good api from where I can fetch synonym of a word(English Language).

Requirement:--

1. User enters a word
2. press fetch button
3. I will display synonym of that word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this one: http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php

Very flexible.